# how to defime routing for multiple subviews

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I am developing and application using durandal. I have two sections in my page with different navigation menu. I am using composition to keep make these subviews. But I am not sure how to define routes for these sections.

Comment: Google child routers in durandal or on Stack and you should get your answer

Comment: Please add code snippet

Answer (score 0):

In your **shell.js**

```
 { route: 'work*details', moduleId: 'profile/index', title: 'Profil', nav: 1, hash: '#profil', authorize: ["User", "Administrator"] },
```

in the subfolder **index.js**

```
var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
        .makeRelative({
            moduleId: 'viewmodels/marketplace',
            fromParent: true
        }).map(userRoute[

            // put you sub nav here

            ]).buildNavigationModel();

    return {
        router: childRouter,
        work: ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(childRouter.navigationModel(), function (route) {
                return route.type == 'intro';
            });
        })
    };
```

the markup

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <!--ko foreach: work-->
        <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
            <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
        </li>
        <!--/ko-->

    </ul>
```

find out more [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html).